# unresolved external symbol when compiling GDAL 1.11.0 on windows

Tags: c++, gdal

I am running into an issue with compiling gdal 1.11.0 following the guide here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnWindows

I am able to run `nmake /f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1800 WIN64=YES` but when doing the install it fails with the following erros:

```
   Creating library gdal_i.lib and object gdal_i.exp
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OGRFeatureStylePuller
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OSRValidate
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OPTGetProjectionMethods
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OGR_G_GetPointCount
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OGRRegisterAll
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GDALSimpleImageWarp@36
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GDALReprojectImage@48
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GDALComputeMedianCutPCT@32
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GDALDitherRGB2PCT@28
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OCTNewCoordinateTransformation
@8
gdal111.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\BIN\amd64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
```

Is that something I can do anything about or is it something thats broken in the source downloaded from http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the arguments could not be passed on command line and needed to be changed in the config file.

Comment: Hi! 
I have the same problem as you. Which arguments do you mean and where is the config file I have to change and what do I have to change?

Comment: "There are lots of options that can be tweaked by hand in the nmake.opt file in the GDAL root directory." from the building windows doc.

Comment: I am using the gisinternal build now instead of building my self though.

Answer (score 7):

The answer provided by Poul is not right. I finally find a way to fix this problem:

1. Find the nmake.opt file under GDAL home folder, open it and search for the definition of 'SYM_PREFIX'. Then change 'SYM_PREFIX=_' to 'SYM_PREFIX=' (remove the underscore).
2. Find the makefile.vc file under GDAL home folder, open it and search for the first definition of 'BASE_INCLUDE' (The other definition is just below it, do not change the wrong one).
   Change from
   `BASE_INCLUDE = /INCLUDE:_GDALSimpleImageWarp@36 /
   /INCLUDE:_GDALReprojectImage@48 /
   /INCLUDE:_GDALComputeMedianCutPCT@32 /
   /INCLUDE:_GDALDitherRGB2PCT@28 /
   /INCLUDE:_OCTNewCoordinateTransformation@8 $(VB6_SAFEARRAYSYM)`
   to:
   `BASE_INCLUDE = /INCLUDE:$(SYM_PREFIX)GDALSimpleImageWarp /
   /INCLUDE:$(SYM_PREFIX)GDALReprojectImage /
   /INCLUDE:$(SYM_PREFIX)GDALComputeMedianCutPCT /
   /INCLUDE:$(SYM_PREFIX)GDALDitherRGB2PCT /
   /INCLUDE:$(SYM_PREFIX)OCTNewCoordinateTransformation $(VB6_SAFEARRAYSYM)`
   .
   In short, replace the '_' with $(SYM_PREFIX), and remove the '@number'.

According to some webpages, this problem may be caused by the change of AMD64 vc++ compiler handling undecorated symbols.

Comment: Actually all I needed to do was uncomment the WIN64 line in the nmake.opt file.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and after set right MSVC_VER(mine VS 2012), problem is solved.

**Nmake Command:**

```
nmake /f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1800 WIN64=yes
```

**MSVC Versions:**

```
MSVC++ 9.0 _MSC_VER == 1500 (Visual Studio 2008)
MSVC++ 10.0 _MSC_VER == 1600 (Visual Studio 2010)
MSVC++ 11.0 _MSC_VER == 1700 (Visual Studio 2012)
MSVC++ 12.0 _MSC_VER == 1800 (Visual Studio 2013)
MSVC++ 14.0 _MSC_VER == 1900 (Visual Studio 2015)
MSVC++ 14.1 _MSC_VER == 1910 (Visual Studio 2017)
```

Comment: Yea, it's import to have the WIN64=yes to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional arguments into the build by uncommenting parts of the nmake.opt file. The below commands worked for me after invoking the batch file located at

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\"

with `vcvarsall.bat amd64`

```
nmake /f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1800 WIN64=yes
nmake /f makefile.vc install MSVC_VER=1800 WIN64=yes    
nmake /f makefile.vc devinstall MSVC_VER=1800 WIN64=yes
```